# Why is value of PATH not retained in an if block

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am seeing some strange behavior of a Windows batch script. When `PATH` is set 
outside an `if` block, its value is retained but the value is not retained when set inside the `if` block.

Here's a minimal .bat file that shows the problem.

```
@echo off

echo %*

set PATH=c:\Windows;
set "PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII;%PATH%"
PATH
set "PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII\managed;%PATH%"
PATH

set PATH=c:\Windows;

set arg=%1
if "%arg%" == "a" (
   echo "------------------------------------------"
   set "PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII;%PATH%"
   PATH
   set "PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII\managed;%PATH%"
   PATH
)
```

The output of the script when invoked with one `a` as the only argument.

```
a
PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII;c:\Windows;
PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII\managed;c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII;c:\Windows;
"------------------------------------------"
PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII;c:\Windows;
PATH=c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII\managed;c:\Windows;
```

As you can see, the directory `"c:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 9.0\UGII"` is missing from the last line of output.

Is this expected?

Is there a way to make this work without requiring `PATH` to be set only once inside the `if` block?

Comment: Aside from the link I posted, you do realize that this does not permanently change the `PATH` variable.  You would need to use `SETX` for that.

Comment: @Squashman, no I did not know that.

Comment: @Squashman, I need to change the PATH only in the script. `setx` is not the right command for my needs. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Then I would advise that you be more careful with which directory paths you remove. Usually not a good idea to remove SYSTEM32.

Comment: @Squashman, of course. The posted code was indended to be a [mcve].